# DataTable ajax Nested Table with search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have created jQuery DataTable with ajax which is working fine but I need to add another nested table inside it and it should be search from parent table. Is it possible !!

**HTML**

```
<table id="gatePass" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>From Date</th>
            <th>To Date</th>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <!--<th style="display:none">itemId</th>-->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var dataTableExample = 'undefined';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadDataTable();
    });

    function loadDataTable() {
        var a = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('GatePass')/items?$select=Id,Title,FromDate,ToDate,Area,OtherOldBuildingArea,OtherNewBuildingArea,WFStatus&$filter=WFStatus eq 'Approved'";
        $.ajax({
            url: a,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: mySuccHandler,
            error: myErrHandler
        });
    }

    function mySuccHandler(data) {
        if (dataTableExample != 'undefined') {
            dataTableExample.destroy();
        }
        dataTableExample = $("#gatePass").DataTable({
            "aaData": data.d.results,
            "aoColumns": [
                 {
                    "className": 'details-control',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                 },
                { mData: "Title" },
                {
                    mData: "FromDate",
                    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                        return moment(data).format('DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm A');
                    }
                },
                {
                    mData: "ToDate",
                    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                        return moment(data).format('DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm A');
                    }
                },
                { mData: "Area" },
                { mData: "WFStatus" },
            ]
        });
    }
    function myErrHandler(data, errCode, errMessage) {
        alert("Error: " + errMessage);
    }
```

What is good for nested table to get data directly from ajax or to make dynamic string and to the table. Issue is if I make dynamic string than I think I cannot search on it. Please help me.

Comment: Did you get the solution? Can you please post the answer?

Comment: Yea I did. Once I reach office then I will post it. At the moment I don't remember

Comment: Milind could please post the solution